# Javascript calendar non-sequential months

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am new to JavaScript and created a calendar that displays all 12 months for a given year and want the ability to add random months for use in a query. I can do this part now however how do I easily check to see if the months are sequential keeping in mind they can be picked in any order. Example: JAN, FEB MAR or FEB, MAR, JAN app will display JAN 1 to MAR 30 but Jan & APR will display a message stating you selected non-sequential values.

Comment: If month1 +- 1 of month2 then...

Answer (score 0):

A simple comparison would work since the date selections are already limited to a single year. In addition, you could easily presort the dates (as shown) to assist the user with the selection.

**Example:**

```js
var month, dates = [new Date('2016-10-01'), new Date('2016-11-01'), new Date('2016-12-01')];

// optional date sort
// dates.sort(function(a,b){ return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0 });

month = dates[0].getMonth();

if (dates[1].getMonth() == (month + 1) && dates[2].getMonth() == (month + 2)) {

  console.info('okay');

} 
else {

  console.info('fail');

}

console.info(JSON.stringify(dates, null, '  '));
```